# Как вывести прелоадер перед загрузкой изображения

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как с помощью javascript выводить прелоадер, пока не загрузится картинка? Важно распознать момент,что картинка загрузилась и вовремя убрать прелоадер и вывести картинку

```
    <img src='/images/photo.jpg' id='photo'>
    <img src='/images/preloader.gif' id='preloader'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот простой пример (https://codepen.io/L2Banners/pen/wMboGg):

HTML:

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
<p>EXEMPLE</p>
```

CSS:

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #333 url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/3.7.0/processing.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        },2000);

    });  
});
```